# Need help using 'this' - cannot use in a static context

Tags: java, this, affinetransform

I understand that static methods must be called but not-static methods must have an instance made. I am trying to make a simple 2D game. I want all my graphics to appear in one window not several different windows for each class which is what was happening. So I decided to make a paintGraphics class with a static updateBackBuffer method that will add an image to a graphics2D variable (named g2d). I tried this code but i got an error that I cannot use this in a static context, how can I get around this?:

```
public static void updateBuffer(Image image, int XPos , int YPos , int Height , int Width ,   int Rotation, AffineTransform trans) {
    trans.translate(XPos,YPos);
    trans.rotate(Rotation);      //More lines will probably be more lines totransform the shape more as the game gets more advanced
    g2d.drawImage(image,trans,this);    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line : `g2d.drawImage(image,trans,this);`, the `this` refers to an instance of a the class that defines `updateBuffer`. Since `updateBuffer` is declared `static`, it cannot use a reference `this`, as `this` is not guaranteed to be initialized.

---

Update

```
public class Foo {
   public Foo() {
      ...
   }

    public static void updateBuffer(Image image, int XPos , int YPos , int Height , int Width , int Rotation, AffineTransform trans, Foo foo) {
        trans.translate(XPos,YPos);
        trans.rotate(Rotation);      //More lines will probably be more lines totransform the shape more as the game gets more advanced
        g2d.drawImage(image,trans,foo); // <-- 'foo' stands in for 'this'

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Image i = new Image();
      int x,y,h,w,r;
      AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
      Foo f = new Foo();
      Foo.updateBuffer(i,x,y,h,w,r,t,f);
   }
}
```

Comment: well how do I fix that then?, that was my original question

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the containing object, why not pass an instance of the object in as a parameter to the static method, ie:

```
public static void updateBuffer(Image image, int XPos , int YPos , int Height , int Width , int Rotation, AffineTransform trans, Object parent)
```